# threejs load big stl file

Tags: three.js

I want to use threejs to display the stl,  I read some sample online.
The problem is that my stl files are quite big(binary format: 28mb), it takes too long to load. 
Is that possible to load part of stl file and display a basic shape, then to load the rest of file?

Comment: There are two main ways. Each requires additional processing model in the editor:
- While loaded model of high quality from the main file asynchronously download the prepared models of low quality and light weight, and replacing it on the base model when it is loaded.
- Break the model into small lightweight parts, load and display each. After downloading all the parts combine them into a single object.

Comment: Best way - display progress indicator of loading.

Comment: Hi @stdob--,  How can you choose which data load first? Each data is in a facet normal, they are in the same level.

Comment: it depends on the design stage and design models. This decision is not the responsibility of the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you working with bufferedgeometry, and take a look at [setDraRange](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.setDrawRange), which set limit for drawing vertices, so create some setInteraval where you increase count of `items(position, normals)` to be produced in Webgl context.